# Add div next to other centered div

Tags: html, css

I want to add a div to the right of other div which is positioned in the center. As shown in the image:

[image]

I have this html so far:

```
<div id= "top-menu-wrapper">
  <div id="top-menu">       
  </div>
  <div id="social">
  </div>
</div>
```

The css:

```
#header #top-menu {
    display           : inline-block;
    width             : 764px;
    height            : 55px;
    margin            : auto;   
}

#header #social {
    display           : inline-block;
    width             : 100px;
    height            : 55px;   
    margin-left       : 25px;

}

#header #top-menu-wrapper {
    display           : block;
    text-align        : center;
    margin-bottom     : 25px;
}
```

Comment: It works for me, I just added colors to the divs so you could see it. (http://jsfiddle.net/nbatothemax/G7uC9/) What probably was the problem is that you have a `#header` ID as the parent to each of these containers, when you haven't given a header container for all of them. Also, if your elements have ID's, you shouldn't need to use parent selectors to get to them because you can just get them right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your widths are fixed, just calculate the left offset of each div, and put it as the left margin without using the central alignment.

Or, if your container is fluid, center the problematic div inside a right-floated subcontainer with the width of

`(top container width - central div width) / 2)` (that represents the remaining space at the right)

You'll probably make it look the best if you use the JavaScript window resize listener to recalculate its position on every resize event. (although you'd prefer to use CSS only, I'd suggest JS for the best results)

Answer (score 0):

Since you use inline-block to display your boxes, parent could have : `text-align:center;` and the second boxe a negative margin of its own width, to pull first box in the middle.

http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/ADsEx

background-colors are used to show where boxes are standing and a ruler is added to check visually horizontal center.

```
#top-menu {
  display           : inline-block;
  width             : 764px;
  height            : 55px;
  background        : green;
}

#social {
  display           : inline-block;
  width             : 100px;
  height            : 55px; 
  margin-right      : -100px; 
  background        : yellow;
}

#top-menu-wrapper {
  text-align        : center;
  min-width         : 990px;
  background        : purple;
}
div {
  vertical-align    : top;
  padding           : 5px 0;
}
.ruler {
  width             : 50%;
  background        : red;
  margin            : 5px 0 ;
}
```

This way, you don't mind parents width, unless you want them 2 always on one line. If so, then a min-width: wide enough can be applied.

Another solution is to add a pseudo of same width of boxe 2.
http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/hipBl

```
body {
  padding           : 2em;
  margin            : 0;
}
#top-menu {
  display           : inline-block;
  width             : 764px;
  height            : 55px;
  background        : green;
}

#social, #top-menu-wrapper:before {
  display           : inline-block;
  width             : 100px;
  height            : 55px; 
  background        : yellow;
}
#top-menu-wrapper:before {
  content           : '';
  height            : 0;
}
#top-menu-wrapper {
  text-align        : center;
  min-width         : 990px;
  background        : purple;
}
div {
  vertical-align    : top;
  padding           : 5px 0;
}
.ruler {
  width             : 50%;
  background        : red;
  margin            : 5px 0 ;
}
```