# ExtJS: 'next to centre'

Tags: extjs

I'd like to achieve [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17582085/add-div-next-to-other-centered-div) in ExtJS 4.2:

[image]

e.g. a centred button, with something (a progress indicator) to its right that doesn't result in the button moving.

All my layouts are currently relative, largely using HBox & VBox, and I'd like to keep it this way rather than using anything absolute to solve this.

There are probably lots of ways to do this, but many of them will be horrible. I guess the 'floating' attribute might play a part, but I can't quite work that out.

Any suggestions?

Comment: you want progress bar width dynamically but I didn't understand your goal. For instance, what is width of the panel? is it also dynamic depends on the window size?

Comment: Yes. Everything is dynamic and resizable, except margins and padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the HBox layout's [pack](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.HBox-cfg-pack) config to display the items in the center, and apply a [margin](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.button.Button-cfg-margin) equal to the progess bar's width to the left side of the button:

```
{
    layout: {
        type: 'hbox',
        pack: 'center'
    },

    items: [{
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'Push me',
        width: 100,
        margin: '0 0 0 100' // margin-left equal to the width of the progress bar
    },{
        xtype: 'progressbar',
        width: 100
    }]
}
```

Also check out [this fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2ua).

Comment: I like this but ideally need it a bit more dynamic. Is there an opportune moment to dynamically get the progress bar's width? I tried doing this in its 'afterRender' event but it was still zero. I suppose a fiddle is to have the PB in a bigger than necessary fixed width container, left aligned.

Comment: It works for me with afterrender (I've updated my [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2ua) accordingly).

Comment: afterRender on the parent container, rather than the progress bar, seems to have done it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt, let me know if it's a problem.

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
var ct = new Ext.panel.Panel({
    width: '100%',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    margin: 10,
    border: true,
    id: 'ppanel',        
    layout: {
        type: 'hbox',
    },

    items: [{
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'Push me',
        width: 100,
        id: 'bbutton'
    },{
        xtype: 'progressbar',
        width: 100,
        id: 'pbar'
    }],
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function() {
            pwidth = Ext.getCmp('ppanel').getWidth();
            bwidth = Ext.getCmp('bbutton').getWidth();
            button = Ext.getCmp('bbutton');
            progrs = Ext.getCmp('pbar');
            bmargin = (pwidth/2 - bwidth/2);
            button.setMargin("0 0 0 "+bmargin);
            progrs.setMargin("0 0 0 10");
        }
    }
});
});
```